# Shortest path in linear time

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose each edge can receive one of two weights $\{r_1,r_2\}$ where $r_1$ and $r_2$ are real and non-negative. And suppose $r_1 \leq r_2$. How do you find the shortest path from a given vertex s to every other vertex in the graph in linear time? ($O(V+E)$)

Comment: A linear time algorithm for single source shortest path problem - http://www.ragibhasan.com/wp-content/uploads/publications/papers/hasan00linear.pdf

Answer (score 3):

The asymptotically best algorithm known for this (well studied) problem is an implementation of [Dijkstra'a algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm), which runs in $O(|E|+ |V|\log|V|)$ time. That is almost but not quite as good as you asked for, so probably you just asked too much.